# Get Error for Python Django Rest Framework Code

Tags: python, django, rest, postman, serialization

I'm new to Django in Python. I have a python Django project called "corr_end" with an app within it called "send_values"

I wrote a serializer, trying to make get/put/post/delete methods available and working through Postman testing.

When I try the get method, it doesn't work in Postman and gives me an error.

I appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/values/dinos

Error from terminal:

Error from terminal:

**Internal Server Error: /values/dinos
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[19/Mar/2020 07:02:00] "GET /values/dinos HTTP/1.1" 500 63860**

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[redacted]/anaconda3/envs/chipseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "[redacted]/anaconda3/envs/chipseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "[redacted]/anaconda3/envs/chipseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)**

I created a Python package 'api' under send_values directory with send_values_api.py containing the serializer.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from ..models import Dinosaur

class DinoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dinosaur
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'species']

    def validate(self, userData):
        if not userData['name']:
            print('name is required')
            return ValidationError
        return userData

    def create(self, userData):
        newDinosaur = Dinosaur.objects.create(**userData)
        newDinosaur.save()
        return newDinosaur

    def update(self, existingDinosaur, userData):
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'species']
        for i in fields:
            fieldValue = userData.get(i, getattr(existingDinosaur, i))
            setattr(existingDinosaur, i, fieldValue)
        existingDinosaur.save()
        return existingDinosaur

class DinoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DinoSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'options']
    queryset = Dinosaur.objects.all()
```

models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Correlations(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.TextField()
    executed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Dinosaur(models.Model):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    species = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py in send_values:

```
from .api.send_values_api import DinoViewSet
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url('dinos', DinoViewSet),
]
```

Note: There's no code in the views.py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`ViewSets`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) are not same as `Views`. You can't add them directly to the urls like Views. Easiest solution here is to use [**`routers`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#using-routers) like this:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'dinos', DinoViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```